# Is it possible to convert existing Android APK into bundle

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play, bundle, code-signing

I have ported some published Android apps from Eclipse to Android Studio.
When Generating a Signed Bundle, I need to sign with the original APK *app-signing key* against the original key-store or the signing fails.

However, to upload it to Google Play I need to sign the bundle with a (different) *Upload key* that I register with Google Play, encrypt the app-signing key with PEPK and upload that for Google to do the actual app-signing. Catch 22.

I could create a new key-store and pretend it is a new app, but Google Play will, I guess, then not recognize that the app is a new version of an existing app.

Am I doing this wrong, or is there a problem updating an existing app from local APK-signing to Google Play signing?

Comment: So are you following the instructions for existing apps: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7384423?hl=en

Comment: Yes. My difficulty is that I cannot sign a bundle created from an existing app (which has an app-signing key used to create a certificate already in the local keystore) with a DIFFERENT key, specifically an Upload key. One possible workaround would be to set up a fresh local keystore to sign the bundle with an Upload key - but any requirement to do this is not mentioned anywhere in Google's instructions...

Comment: From the link: `If you upload and sign your APK with an upload key, Google will re-sign the APK with your deployment key.` So if you are signing for upload use the upload key. How you manage the keys on your side is your choice (i.e. upload specific keystore).

Answer (score 1):

You need to:

1. Encrypt your *existing* app signing key with PEPK.
2. Create a *new* upload key and export the certificate in PEM format.
3. Upload those two files in the Play Console when you enroll in App Signing.

Note that in step #1, you need to find that same keystore you used to sign your existing app.

The instructions in the Play Console should give more details with the commands to run, but let me know if something needs clarification.

Comment: Hi Pierre can you help me here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74843452/sign-existing-app-from-apk-to-aab-problem