# Sign existing app from apk to aab problem

Tags: java, android, google-play, apk

I have an  android app that i always upload to google play as an apk with a keystore from 2018 and I use google signing which is recommended as they say, recently I signed the app and exported it as an aab with the same  old keystore but now old users can't update the app and new users can't install the app

[image]

**Can anyone help me please ,is  What i did is wrong and if so  How to fix it**

Comment: Could you please share your Gradle file, also have you tried it with another device, I've faced the same issue with an app (not mine) and after clearing the Google Play cache, the app installed successfully

Comment: Have you done any key upgrade or key rotation on the Play Console? And have you installed the app locally on your device (e.g. through Android Studio or ADB)?